# Encode 2D Array in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, encoding

I have a custom object with two 2D arrays as follows:

```
float a[5][5];
float b[5][10];
```

And I want to encode this object:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    // Encode a
    // Encode b
}
```

How can I encode and decode these 2D arrays? I couldn't find an appropriate method to do this operation.
Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a struct with those:

```
typedef struct myStruct {

    float a[5][5];
    float b[5][10];

}MyStruct;
```

Then use NSValue to encode them as objects.

```
MyStruct i;
memset(&i, 0, sizeof(i));
//Set values on struct

NSValue *v = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&i objCType:@encode(MyStruct)];
```

Now, you can treat your struct as an object and use then with NSArrays and so on.

To read the values you can use:

```
MyStruct i;

[v getValue:&i];
```

I did it like this to work with streams and legacy servers and it worked smoothly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Stick them into objective-c containers for the encoding/decoding process.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pre-built method for that - you would need to write it yourself. The simplest way would be to write two `int`s first for the number of rows and the number of columns, and then write all `R*C` elements one by one.

Decoding is equally simple - read the two ints for `R` and `C`, and then run two nested loops reading the `float`s.

Define two helper functions for that to avoid copy-pasting the same code twice.